# Set monitor refresh rate and make sure it was set correctly?

Tags: display, display-resolution, monitor, xrandr

So I rand `xrandr` and got his output:

```
   1920x1080     60.05*+  59.93    48.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00
```

I have Monitor that supports 240 Hz.

So I tried this: `xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 240`

But running `xrandr`, I get `1920x1080     60.00 + 119.98*   50.00    59.94`.

Does it mean, that Ubuntu set it to only `119.98`? Or it is just showing it incorrectly?

P.S. My laptop has only Intel integrated graphics card if that matters.

**Update**

After following `xrandr` manual, I was able to add new mode with `240 Hz`, but still can't apply it. Also I could not name it for example as `1920x1080_240.00`, because when trying to use it, it would error out that no such mode was found. So I used name `240mode`.

Now trying to use new mode, I get this:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 240mode --verbose

crtc 0:      240mode 239.88 +1920+0 "HDMI1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
crtc 3: revert
```

Comment: Are you sure `--output HDMI1` is correct as every output of xrandr I have seen lists things as `HDMI-1` `HDMI-2` `DP-1` etc. Also it may be that your graphics adaptor will not output at that refresh rate. Update your question with exact make/model of laptop and exact graphics adaptor details. Also I would let people know EXACTLY what commands you ran and in which order rather than saying "I was able to add new mode" as somebody may spot something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the man page for `xrandr` the `--rate` parameter says:

> This marks a preference for refresh rates close to the specified value, when multiple modes have the same name, this  will select the one with the nearest refresh rate.

So you are not necessarily setting the refresh rate to 240 with that command, only saying "set to the closest rate that the system knows about". Although it's not clear why the system is not detecting higher refresh rate modes from your monitor if it supports them.

What you may want to do is add an undetected resolution using `cvt` to generate a modeline and then `xrandr` to add the modeline as a new resolution, then changing to that new resolution. See the `Troubleshooting` section here: [Xrandr info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr)

And try `cvt 1920 1080 240` or `cvt -r 1920 1080 240`

I would take note of the tip about using sleep to reverse a resolution change too if you are experimenting and don't want to reboot if you change to an invalid resolution.

Comment: Tried suggestion, but seems something is wrong. Provided details in question.